# ¿es posible generar doble scrollbar en un mismo div?

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

dentro de una  se creó una tabla que contiene muchos elementos horizontales y verticales, para poder ver los elementos que desbordan la pantalla horizontalmente, se debe hacer scroll vertical para localizar el scrollbar para poder moverlo, en ese caso, se necesita tener otro scrollbar al inicio de la tabla, ¿es posible tener dos scrollbar en una misma div?

Comment: Solo es posible 1 vertical y otro horizontal. Si tú tienes más, es que son varios elementos anidados.

Answer (score 1):

en el css, con la propiedad "overflow: scroll;" se debería poder solucionar. Debes aplicársela al contenedor padre.

Comment: lo que necesito es que tenga dos scroll, uno arriba y uno abajo, la propiedad que propones genera el scroll vertical y el horizontal, necesito dos horizontales

Comment: @AndresBeltrán Lo que pasa es que no se entiende lo que quieres, si puedes volver a explicar sería fabuloso

Comment: No sé si sea posible poner una barra de scroll abajo y otra arriba, con el "overflow: auto" se pondría la barra de scroll pero solamente abajo